# Union of two subsets is sum of the span?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a Vector Space, and let $S_1, S_2 $ be subsets of V.

Prove that $$\text{span}(S_1 \cup S_2 )= \text{span}(S_1) +\text{span}(S_2)$$

I have no clue where to start.  Hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$v\in\text{Span}\,(S_1\cup S_2)\implies \exists\,v_1,...,v_n\in S_1\,,\,w_1,...,w_m\in S_2\;\;s.t. $$

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i+\sum_{j=1}^mb_jw_j\in\text{Span}\,S_1+\text{Span}\,S_2$$
$$\text{So Span}\,(S_1 \cup S_2)\subseteq\text{Span}\,S_1+\text{Span}\,S_2 $$
Now *you try* the other direction...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that span$\{S_1\} \subseteq span\{S_1 \cup S_2\}$ and similarly for span{$S_2$}.
Use that span of a set is a vector space to show RHS is contained in LHS.

Then show that $S_1 \cup S_2 \subseteq span\{S_1\}+span\{S_2\}$. Since RHS is a vector space, LHS is contained in RHS. Hence two sides are equal.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint**: $\text{span}(S)$ means a space which is the smallest in that contain $S$.

So we just need to prove:

> First, $S_1\cup S_2$ is contained in $\text{span}(S_1)+\text{span}(S_2)$;
>
> Second, for any $W$ is a subspace of $V$ which contains $S_1\cup S_2$, then we have that $W$ must contain $\text{span}(S_1)+\text{span}(S_2)$.